# Best practice to log out everything related to HttpRequest and HttpResponse

Tags: java

Im executing a http request like this:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/test");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

What is the best way to log out everything about the request/response? I mean like what method was used for request and what url and all the headers and response code and response message body and so on.

Edit:

At the moment i worked out something like this:

```
    private static void logHttpRequest(HttpMessage httpMessage) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        addHeaders(httpMessage, builder);
        builder.append(httpMessage.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Request:\n" + builder.toString());
    }

    private static void logHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(httpResponse.getStatusLine() + "\n");
        addHeaders(httpResponse, builder);
        builder.append(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
        System.out.println("Response:\n" + builder.toString() + "\n");
    }

    private static void addHeaders(HttpMessage httpMessage, StringBuilder builder) {
        Header[] headers = httpMessage.getAllHeaders();
        if (headers != null) {
            for (Header header : headers) {
                builder.append(header.toString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anything else that should be logged? Can anything be done better/more optimal?

Comment: http is state less you have to deal with session not with http

Answer (score 0):

I think this primarily depends on context and your requirements. Keep in mind though, that huge amounts of logging is also not smart. For example, you should log *exceptions* at a high log level, eg. SEVERE or ERROR (depends on the logging framework you're using). However, messages like, "trying to make a GET request to http://soAndSo/whatevz" could do with lower log level of, say DEBUG, so you could switch your code to log DEBUG level messages when something bad happens in production.

Something I have typically seen people do with the *response* is that they definitely log ERROR if there's *no response at all* but when there *is* a response, it's imperative to check the http status code of the response and if it's not what you expect it to be (typically 200/2xx), you log the response body, headers, etc at ERROR level.

When making POST or PUT requests with some body, try and see if it's useful to log the request body and headers if any at, say, INFO or DEBUG level. These things sometimes help in tracing out failure scenarios or lost requests/lost data.

At the consuming end too, your system should *ideally* have a monitor on the no.of/rate of ERROR level messages otherwise you'll come to know of something very bad only *after* it happens, which is not favourable.